# Proper way to check if user is authorized on the backend (laravel 5.4 & tymon-jwt)

Tags: php, laravel, jwt, angular2-jwt

I'm using Angular 4 and Laravel 5.4 & Tymon JWT. Currently I just pass the token from the frontend which is stored in local storage to the backend and Tymons default auth does its work. However I have some columns in my database like `canView`, `canUpdate` that I check before allowing a user to do something. I just parse the token, get the user from the token, and check the column. What is a better/safer way to do this?

```
doSomething(Request $request) {
    $thisUser = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate();
    $user = User::find($thisUser->id);

    if ($user->canUpdate) {
        //allow them to update
    }
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong about it. Keep in mind that `tymondesigns/jwt-auth` only provides authentication, it doesn't provide a way to manage authorizations. For that I recommend using `Zizaco/entrust`.

Comment: I've looked at entrust but I'm not sure how to implement the middleware to handle all ACL (I've only found an example using roles)

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve but the documentation has some good examples: https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust#middleware